# When I click a Product, it gives me error page. Says it is the mini-cart

Tags: error, mini-cart

I am using the Harvest Template on Magento 1.9 and the template is from Themeforest.  My biggest question is how do I either Disable the minicart for a little bit if not required or is this a Theme issue or a Configuration issue?  Magento is large enough I am sure it isn't a bug.  It's my first Magento site, but I do know code.

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Minicart' in /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/Mage.php:595

```
protected function _getBlockInstance($block, array $attributes=array())
    {
        if (is_string($block)) {
            if (strpos($block, '/')!==false) {
                if (!$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block)) {
                    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
                }
            }
            if (class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block)) {
                $block = new $block($attributes);
            }
        }
        if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
        }
        return $block;
    }
```

The function above is the offending function from the layout.php file, and the last Mage::throwException is the line of code that gave the error.

```
2016-03-30T15:07:34+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Minicart' in /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('checkout/cart_m...', Array)
#2 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('checkout/cart_m...', 'minicart_head')
#3 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('checkout/cart_m...', 'minicart_head')
#4 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/st3rnz/public_html/newcumberlandpro/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Minicart` is a core block which comes under `Mage_Checkout` module. So in normal case, the chance of occurrence of this error is NIL unless that file is missing.

So I seriously suspect that file is missing in your Magento instance. Please check it and replace it with `Minicart.php` file corresponding to your magento version.

You can check whether the file exist at  : `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Minicart.php` . If it is not there, please place [***Minicart.php***](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Minicart.php) file there.